# Laravel 5 and Laravel 5.1 "Class 'Model Name' not found", is there better solution?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, models, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel, but I have some problems.
In Laravel 4 all works fine. I make all steps for database config. , creating Model and all works fine.

In Laravel 5/5.1 There is no folder Models, by default Models are stored in App folder, but if I create Model 'Example.php':

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Example extends Model
{
protected $table = 'examples';
}
```

and try to get it in routes.php :

```
Route::get('/', function(){

$example = new Example;

return $example::all();
});
```

I see an error: "Class 'Example' not found".
I found the solution just to add in route.php:

```
use App\Example;
```

But, is there better solution ?
I must add 'use' for each Model ?
For the example if I have 2-3-4-5-etc Models I must type:

```
use App\Example;
use App\Example1;
use App\Example2;
```

Yes, I search in Laravel documentation, other forums, etc. If you do same steps like Laravel 5.1 documentation - database configuration, create model, use it,  you will get this error.

Adding path to composer.json "autoload" and - composer dump-autoload, does not help.

Comment: Then you must use : "use App\Models\Example;", for each Model, I am asking other.

Comment: You must get used to it, it brings a ton of organization to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have two classes `Example`, one is a model and the other one is something else, located elsewhere.
PHP can't know which one are you trying to use.
That is why if you try to use a Class in a file like routes.php it will not be able to find it, unless you specify it or use it with it's full path like `App\Model\Example`.

Now, a good question is why are you having logic inside the routes.php?
For sake of code clarity and separation on concepts it is unadvised that you write actual logic (or view) or anything other than the definition of the routes in that file.

The suggestion is that you actually refactor your code and move each set of logic that handles the requests to actual Controllers and then just define which controller handles which path there.

That way you will end up with no `use` statements there and your `routes.php` will actually be very clean and easy to read and you will end up with something like this:

```
Route::resource('example', 'ExampleController');
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Which would also tell you where to find what logic.

Answer (score 0):

U can also use a direct method like this

```
    Route::get('/', function()
{
$example = new App\Example;
return $example::all();
});
```

But still I would prefer the default method. As U can see now I have to **App** in front every time I uses a model.